# When importing a log file as input from Fluent bit and loading the log into S3, the data format in the log file is different

Tags: java, json, amazon-s3, logging, fluent-bit

First of all, this is my log data.

{
"hostname" : "test",
"serverTimestamp" : "2023-10-18T18:37:42.048",
"serverIp" : "-",
"jobCode" : "-",
"jobName" : "-"
}

Log data loaded into S3.

{"date":"2023-10-18T10:02:38.614367Z","appname":"30327b422843400d953a2852ec2ac0d3.log","filename":"/fluent-bit/logs/SEARCH_LOGS/20231018/2023101819/aa1b d99e095de771-30327b422843400d953a2852ec2ac0d3. log","log":"{"}
{"date":"2023-10-18T10:02:38.614369Z","appname":"30327b422843400d953a2852ec2ac0d3.log","filename":"/fluent-bit/logs/SEARCH_LOGS/20231018/2023101819/aa1b d99e095de771-30327b422843400d953a2852ec2ac0d3. log","log":" \"hostname\" : \"test\","}

....

The log is too long, so I'll skip it.

As above, the log contains one line at a time: date, appname, filename
If you paste it like this, it won't come out like the original.

Can you tell me why?

Below is my conf configuration code.

-------------------Fluent-bit.conf -----------

```
[SERVICE]
   Flush        10
   Log_Level    info
   Daemon       off

[INPUT]
   Name         tail
   Path         /fluent-bit/logs/SEARCH_LOGS/*/*/*.log
   Path_Key     filename
   Tag          SEARCH_LOGS.*
   Parser       json
   Refresh_Interval  10
   Buffer_Chunk_Size 10M
   Buffer_Max_Size   10G

[FILTER]
   Name  lua
   Match  *
   script  /fluent-bit/etc/helper.lua
   call  extract_app_fields

[OUTPUT]
   Name                s3
   Match               SEARCH_LOGS.*
   region              ap-northeast-2
   bucket              dev-fluentbit
   upload_timeout      20s
   use_put_object      On
   static_file_path    On
   store_dir           /fluent-bit/logs/fluentbit
   upload_chunk_size   3m
   s3_key_format       /logs/$TAG[3]/%Y%m%d/%Y%m%d%H/$TAG[6].log.gz
   s3_key_format_tag_delimiters .
   compression         gzip
```